# I Want a Search Box With a Button Where I Can Copy Any Of The Image URL And I Want That Image To Be Displayed On The Same Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is the image that shows my requirements

[image]

i wrote my code like this..
html:

```
<input type="search" id="linkit">
<a href="" id="hp" onclick="searchit()">clickme</a>
```

javascript:

```
function searchit() {
   document.getElementById('hp').href=(("https://www.google.com/search?q=") + (document.getElementById("linkit");
```

its working but getting the given image url page in another window but i want result also in the same page.

Comment: buddy will do it but help me in coding this

Comment: You need to use the apis from google. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Try https://www.google.com.ng/search?rlz=1C1AVNG_enNG797NG797&ei=t0JkW6bTAorBlwSTsoiYBg&q=add+google+search+to+website&oq=add+google+search&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l10.196602.201987.0.202710.17.10.0.7.7.0.733.1407.3-2j6-1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.10.1487....0.NbVofpa1LP0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="search" id="linkit">

<button onclick="searchPic()">Search Image</button>
<div>
<img id="myImage" src="" style="width:100px">
</div>


<script>
function searchPic()
{
 searchValue= document.getElementById('linkit').value;
    alert(searchValue);
 document.getElementById('myImage').src = searchValue;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

copy and paste any Image Url given below or any valid image url for testing

1. https://placeimg.com/640/480/any
2. http://via.placeholder.com/350x150

Comment: please vote up and accept this as you answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="result" />

function searchit() {
    document.getElementById('result').src = (("http://via.placeholder.com/350x") + (document.getElementById("linkit").value))};
```

Hello,

your problem is that you are trying to create a link, instead of display an image. You should instead change the src of the image. 
At the code above, i have added an image to hold the result of the query and i am updating the src part of the image with the value of the input. Thus, getting the wanted result.

Comment: I think my answer is now better, thanks for the input.